# How to rotate labels by the same angle as the map in the composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

Does someone know if it is possible to make the labels rotate the same angle as the map in the composer?
I'm trying using the expression `attribute( $map, rotation)` in the data defining placement, but it doesn't work.

Comment: similar question: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129507/label-placement-on-rotated-map-in-qgis

Answer (score 3):

Try using the expression:  attribute( $atlasfeature , 'Rotation').

I used that when I had to rotate labels in an atlas by the rotation value in the coverage layer, and it worked.  You have to use this expression in each feature you want labeled and rotated.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon the answer by guest above (thanks!), this is the updated syntax for usage in QGIS 3.x.

```
attribute(@atlas_feature, 'ColumnWithRotationValue')
```