# QGIS 3x conditional rotation of the label

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I need to rotate only one label from three seen below

[image]

I found some solutions here:

[How to rotate labels by the same angle as the map in the composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130093/how-to-rotate-labels-by-the-same-angle-as-the-map-in-the-composer/325031)

[QGIS Labels Rotation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/298349/29431)

and also here:

[Using Trigonometry To Place And Orientate Labels](https://ieqgis.wordpress.com/2017/07/14/using-trigonometry-to-place-and-orientate-labels/)

But it looks like they are referred for all labels belonging to the given layer. I just want to set the condition for for rotating one of them.

My expression could look like this:

```
 CASE
  WHEN "fid" = 18 then rotation 'degrees 45'
 End
```

but QGIS says, that my expression is invalid.

Is anyone able to help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotation accepts `int`, `double` or `string`(including number) value.

```
CASE
  WHEN "fid" = 18 THEN 45 
  WHEN "fid" = 28 THEN '45'
  WHEN "fid" = 38 THEN 45.0
END
```