# Print Composer rotates map and labels stay unrotated using QGIS 2.8.3

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have seen [these](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129507/label-placement-on-rotated-map-in-qgis?lq=1) [questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130093/how-to-rotate-labels-by-the-same-angle-as-the-map-in-the-composer?lq=1) regarding label rotation and map rotation via the print composer. One of them explains that the labels are rotated with the map, which I am looking for but am unable to get working for QGIS 2.8.3.

This first image shows the labels correctly placed, in the case where I have set my print composer map rotation to 0. They are set on the perimeter of the land parcels.
[image]

The second image shows what happens when I set my map rotation (270) to fit the map contents correctly into the desired paper size. The labels stay where they were, while the map rotates. Adding 270 as the rotation parameter on the labeled layer has not helped.

[image]

This is how I set up my labels:
[image]
[image]

This is how I rotated the print composer map:
[image]

Not sure if this could have anything to do with it, but the labels are a concatenation of two fields (e.g. concat("field1", "field2")).
*Edit* : This doesn't seem to make a difference for my data.

Comment: Looks fine here with my line labels. Couild it be that the position of your labels is data-defined?

Comment: @underdark This screen capture shows labels of polygons that were placed based on perimeter, on the line, depending on position. No data-defined positioning. I will send a screen capture of the options window when i get to work. Would you be willing to post an example of yours, working, with the options you defined?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine here in 2.14. Can you spot any differences? Btw, concat() doesn't seem to affect it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see any differences up front, do you (see added images)? It is true that I am using QGIS 2.8.3 and not 2.14. I may try to update, but if it's not related to the QGIS version I would prefer not to.

Comment: You could update to 2.8.7 if you are not comfortable with 2.14.0. QGIS 2.8.7 is the current LTR ("super stable version"). Labels look fine in it here.